# Let $V = P_3(C)$, and $β = \{i,(x−i),(x−i)^2,(x−i)^3\}$. Find $[p]_β$ for an arbitrary polynomial $p ∈V.$

Tags: linear-algebra

I have tried this but it's so tricky. also does this mean polynomials will have complex coefficients? what I thought was I need to multiply 4th basis vector with the coefficient of $x^3$ then subtract everything else using 3rd basis vector then do the same for the rest.

Comment: That will certainly work.  You can also use Taylor series, which work for complex polynomials just as they do for real polynomials.

Comment: I haven't solved this myself, but your suggestion is how I would try to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any polynomial in $P_3 \left( \mathbb{C} \right)$ will look like $p \left( x \right) = a_0 + a_1 x + a_2 x^2 + a_3 x^3$, where $a_0, a_1, a_2, a_3 \in \mathbb{C}$. We are given a basis $\left\lbrace \iota, \left( x - \iota \right), \left( x - \iota \right)^2, \left( x - \iota \right)^3 \right\rbrace$. Thus, if $\alpha_1, \alpha_2, \alpha_3, \alpha_4 \in \mathbb{C}$ are such that

$$p \left( x \right) = \alpha_1 \iota + \alpha_2 \left( x - \iota \right) + \alpha_3 \left( x - \iota \right)^2 + \alpha_4 \left( x - \iota \right)^3$$

Then, we get a system of equations

\begin{align*}
\iota \alpha_1 - \iota \alpha_2 - \alpha_3 - \iota \alpha_4 &= a_0 \\
\alpha_2 - 2 \iota \alpha_3 - 3 \alpha_4 &= a_1 \\
\alpha_3 - 3 \iota \alpha_4 &= a_2 \\
\alpha_4 &= a_3
\end{align*}

On solving this, we get $\alpha_1 = - \iota a_0 + a_1 + \iota a_2 - a_3, \alpha_2 = a_1 + 2 \iota a_2 - 3 a_3, \alpha_3 = a_2 + 3 \iota a_3, \alpha_4 = a_3$. Thus, $\left[ p \right]_{\beta} = \left( - \iota a_0 + a_1 + \iota a_2 - a_3, a_1 + 2 \iota a_2 - 3 a_3, a_2 + 3 \iota a_3, a_3 \right)$.